# Ajax $.post not working in Firefox

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I read a lot questions and answers about this problem, but noone solved mine.

So i have a simple form:

```
<form action="#" name="pm" id="pm" method="post">
    <input onclick="sendPM()" name="pmSubmit" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

And the following function:

```
function sendPM() {
    $.post("something.php").then(function(data) {
    });
}
```

In "something.php" i doing a simple `INSERT INTO` to my database.
This code works perfectly in IE but dont work in Firefox.
I dont know, what can i do to solve this.

Pls if anyone can help me, will save a lot of time for me.

Comment: *but dont work in Firefox* => we need more information: version of FF, of JQ, what do you mean by doesn't work? It does nothing? Throw an error?

Comment: I use the latest Firefox version: 51.0.1 and the JQ version is 3.1.1.
If i runinng in FF, it does nothing. No error message. But in IE the code run perfectly.

Comment: The function `sendPM()` is called normally?

Comment: The function is work in Firefox too, but that "$.post" doesn't.

Comment: What is the output of the request in FF?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like magic, but fixed it. Change
 onclick="sendPM()"
to
 onclick="sendPM(); return false"

I don't know why, but now both Chrome and Firefox perform the ajax call. Previously firefox did not even make the connection to the server...

Comment: That is because clicking on the input, which is actually a submit button, will submit the form and reload the page. Some browsers will not send out an AJAX call because the page is immediately reloaded.